# Почему в первом предложении определяемое слово в придаточно определительном предложении является подлежащим (книгу), а во втором нет?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

1. Он взял книгу, которая была в нашей библиотеке
2. Я прочитал книгу, которую написал один египетский писатель

Comment: Потому что именительный падеж (которая) всегда подлежащее. А не именительный падеж (которую) - никогда.

Comment: Потому что во втором предложении автор действия писатель.